# MySql database connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have an ASP.NET application, that connects to a mysql database. If on the server I run the web site in visual studio (which uses development server), it can connect to the mysql database correctly.

However, if on that same server I use IIS, an exception `'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts'` is thrown. It is configured to use an application pool with identity as `'ApplicationPoolIdentity'`.

Connection string is like:

```
<add name="MYSQLConnectionString" connectionString="uid=name;server=111.11.111.111;Pwd=password;database=dbname" providerName ="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: Is the IIS server running on your development machine or did you deploy your application on a server? If you deployed your application on a web server did you check with your network administrator that this web server can access the MySQL database server?

Comment: I added connection string in the question. The server is the production server (windows server 2008), on which I both try to run it with VS2010 (works) and under IIS (does not work)

Comment: You have VS2010 running on your production server?

Comment: Yes my client installed it there temporarily to debug the site. Actually it's not a production server yet.

Comment: Maybe http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,44644,44644 is a possible reason, will check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site was not installed in the root, but as an application in the default web site. If we run it as the root site, it works. Don't know why exactly though.

Answer (score 0):

When your debugging with Visual Studio the account is local admin and has rights to everything most likely. The IIS default application pool account does not have these elevated privileges. Make sure the account that your IIS site application pool is running under has the correct permissions, or temporarily change the account to be local system to see if it is a permssions related issue. You can use [`FileMon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to trace what files or registry entries the default account is having trouble accessing.

[EDIT]

Most likely you installed MySQL to someplace like `C:\MySQL` and you just need to grant the IIS application pool account read access to that directory, and possibly a registry entry or two.